# How do I import vue3-toastify globally and call it on other pages?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, toast

I downloaded this package, it works. I have no problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-toastify?activeTab=readme

What I want to do is to import this once in my main.ts file so that there is no need to import it on other pages.

my main.ts;

```
// Vue Toast
import Vue3Toastify, {type ToastContainerOptions} from 'vue3-toastify';
app.use(Vue3Toastify, {
    autoClose: 3000,
    position: 'top-right',
    theme: "light",
    pauseOnFocusLoss: false,
} as ToastContainerOptions)
```

I tried the import method they gave in their documentation, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a service to do it.
For example, having a service function that takes only the title, text and type
With that, you are able to achieve it

Comment: When I type service, I will need to import the service. I just need to import globally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).